How to handle different topics with different data types in Telegraf?
We have three topics in our MQTT input. Two are boolean, one is a float. We use an InfluxDB as output.
e.g. for our topics:

Test/Data/IsActive (bool)
Test/Data/IsHidden (bool)
Test/Data/Speed (float)

How do we handle this in our Telegraf config?
